# Disabling iMessage Reactions iOS 10+

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

Many teams I interact with use iMessage as part of their productivity suite for quick, secure communications between each other. The new features introduced to iMessage by iOS 10 and above are causing some *interesting* problems.

Is it possible to disable Reactions in iMessage so that inadvertent love hearts, etc are sent by those with the occasional sausage finger?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable or "reduce" motion throughout iOS. Disadvantage: Not only iMessage will deactivate special effects, but **Apps will also open in a "not so flashy" way.**

To try it out:

> 1. Open Settings.
> 2. Tap on General.
> 3. Tap on Accessibility.
> 4. Tap on Reduce Motion.
> 5. Tap the switch on the right side of Reduce Motion to turn it on and disable iMessage effects in the Messages app on your iPhone, iPad, or
>      iPod.

Comment: Thank you @gruberb. Will this disable the sending of Reactions or only the receiving of them?

Comment: The reaction will be deactivated then, but be sure and test it)